# How to make unstructured excel data into structure data in SSIS by C#?

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I have excel file which contain unstructured data  i.e single excel file contain 2 types of data blue color is project planed data and down green color has proj actual data.
planed data for date column not coming on same rows it coming just below to that rows and actual data coming on proper rows.

[image: Excel]

How we can make 1 source excel into two separate excel 1 for actual and 1 for planed data and planed data value should be on same rows so that i can load excel file into table by SSIS.